# Jekyll is outputing Gemfile, Gemfile.lock on build. How can / should I prevent this?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

`jekyll build` is creating a Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in my `_site` directory.

Two questions:

1. Should I be concerned about including those files in production?
2. If yes, how can I prevent them from being generated?

Open to any answer, including the yet-not-obvious-to-me.

Thank you!

Here is a screenshot of my environment.  You can see that Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are created *within* `_site`.

[image]

Comment: Can you please send us the output of the `jekyll build`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `_config.yml`, add :

```
exclude:
 - Gemfile
 - Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to have only `_site` directory placed on production server. If you have the whole Jekyll project placed on production server make sure that `_site` directory is marked as root and therefore files on the same or higher level cannot be accessed. In that case presence of Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files does not matter.

I have a Rake task that deploys the Jekyll `_site` directory to production server using rsync.

```
desc "Deploy site"
task :deploy do
  command = "jekyll build && \
    rsync -avz --delete _site/ myserver:/var/www/mysite/"
  sh command
end
```

This is myserver configuration in .ssh config

```
Host myserver
  User USERNAME
  Hostname IP_ADDRESS
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myserver/id_rsa
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: Plus one for best practice.  I acknowledge and _think_ I understand your point. I am only deploying `_site` to production.    I've edited my question for clarity: The Gemfiles are being created *within* `_site`.